# Regular Expression to avoid negative values

Tags: regex

I am totally new to creating my own regular expressions. I have one reg ex developed my team member as listed below

```
  ^\s*-?\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,4})?\s*$
```

This will ensure that the value entered is having a maximum of 3 digits and may or may not have a negative sign.

[RegExp Calculator](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/html/revalid.php)

If I test with a value, “-1000” it will say the entered value does not meet the requirements and an error will be shown to the user.

I need to modify the expression in such way that:

`If a “-“ sign is there, it can have more than 3 digits and decimals. [But if the user enter a “-“ and any alphabets, it should not match ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change it to this one :

```
^\s*(\d{1,3}|-\d+)(\.\d{1,4})?\s*$
```

The first part in the form `(a|b)` means `a` or `b`. It means that the part before the comma is either

- 1 to 3 digits
- or `-` followed by at least one digit

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain why you modified the below one? `^\s*(\d{1,3}|-\d{1,})(\.\d{1,4})?\s*$`

Comment: I just thought that `\d+` was cleaner than `\d{1,}`. It's the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `|`(OR) operator in regex

```
^(\d{1,3}([.]\d{1,4})?|-\d+([.]\d+)?)$
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to validate if a number is between -999 and 999 please parse it to an Integer and check -999 < x < 999.